# How to refresh row of DataGrid when DataGrid is binded to DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, datatable

DataGrid is binded to some DataTable.
User changed some values. I want to mark changed row with some color.
I've done it. But how to notify DataGrid, that current row values have been changed?

P.S. I use trigger on currentRow.Row.RowState for indicating changed row. I don't want to refresh ALL ItemsSource - it operation is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best decision but it works as I expect:

```
dataView.ListChanged += (o, e) =>
{
    if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
    {
        DataRowView row = ((DataView)o)[e.NewIndex];
        if(row != null)
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(DataRowView).GetMethod("RaisePropertyChangedEvent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            method.Invoke(row, new object[] { "Row" });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines may help mate.... Its not exact, you may have to call this on a different event handle.. but it should give you a point in the correct direction!

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            int colIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
            int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;

            DataGridViewRow theRow = dgvOutstandingReports.Rows[rowIndex];


            theRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
        }
```